# Transition matrix generated by throwing 5 dice

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> You throw five dice and set aside those dice that show sixes. Throw the
>   remaining dice and then again set aside the sixes. Continue until you
>   get all sixes. Exhibit the transition matrix for the associated Markov
>   chain, where $X_n$ is the number of sixes after $n$ throws.

I figured that the matrix should have $6$ states, that is state space $S=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}.$ Just by thinking about the first entry, $P_{00}$ we can think "starting with $0$ sixes, what is the probability that on the first throw, we throw $0$ sixes?". To do that, we simply need to throw each die with probability $5/6$, that is $P_{00}=(5/6)^5\approx 0.4018$, which is correct.

Same reasoning for $P_{01}$ gives $P_{01}=(1/6)^1\cdot (5/6)^4\approx 0.08037.$ This is incorrect, for the correct answer here one should apparently multiply the answer with 5. Why? Why did we not need to do that in $P_{00}?$

The general matrix element is given by

$$P_{ij}={5-i\choose j-i}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{j-i}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{5-j}, \quad \forall \quad 0\leq i,j\leq 5. \tag{1}$$

I'm trying to build this formula step by step, intuitivly, but I fail to understand the binomial. Can someone give me an explanation on how to construct $(1)?$

Comment: The $P_{01}$ that you’ve computed is the probability that a _specific_ die shows a six. That one die could be any one of the five dice, though, so you’ve undercounted.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the case for just two dice:  then you have a transition matrix where $X_n \in \{0, 1, 2\}$.  What is the dimension of this matrix?  Then if $X_n = 0$, what is the chance that $X_{n+1} = 0$?  What kind of outcomes correspond to such an event?  Similarly, what is the chance that $X_{n+1} = 2$ if $X_n = 0$?  Finally, based on these previous results, what is the chance that $X_{n+1} = 1$ if $X_n = 0$?

Then do the same for $X_n = 1$:  Is it possible that $X_{n+1} = 0$ if $X_n = 1$?

Finally, consider $X_n = 2$.  Is this an absorbing state?

If you answer these correctly, then think about how this generalizes to more than two dice.